# Undefined index: HTTP_HOST

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes, backend

So I installed this theme and I'm things are not showing up when I'm logged into the backend. Site seems to be showing up fine when I'm logged out of wordpress. I think i've narrowed the problem down to Undefined index: HTTP_HOST PHP Error. It's linked to the themes main core plugin.

```
    public function get_settings(){
    // Get permalink
    $permalink = get_the_permalink();
    if (empty($permalink)){
        $permalink = 'http://' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
```

Could Anyone please explain to me what this code does and why it would be causing an Undefined Index?

Comment: What is the php version? This code is simple saying if your server is having ssl than your url will have https request else http. Tell me php version.

Comment: Running PHP version: 5.6.30

Answer (score 0):

Check with below code.

```
 public function get_settings(){
// Get permalink
$permalink = get_the_permalink();
if (!isset($permalink)){
    $permalink = 'http://' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Sorry for code formatting i am online from mobile so not able to beautify the code

Comment: is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500. Caused it to crash =\